# Netbeans 8.0.2 does not completes code

Tags: php, netbeans-8

I have a problem with Netbeans. 
I started to use the code completion, but it is not working as I expected.
Giving the

```
/** @var type
```

comment does it for $paramplaceholders, but somehow $stmt can not be recognized.
Of course I tried it with

```
/** @var mysqli_stmt $stmt
```

, but the result was the same.

[image: $stmt does not complete]

Any idea?
Thanks,
SanTa

Answer (score 0):

You are using the vdoc the wrong way around.

you should write `/* @var $stmt mysqli_stmt */`

So it should be `@var $var_name Class_Name`

Comment: Does that explain wgy $paramplaceholders can work? Indeed, with the sinlge asterisk Netbeans doesn't even make @var bold.I tried it though, but it didn't work.